# GA4 BigQuery Export is showing multiple psudo_user_ids for a single session_id

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I am running the following query in BQ.

```
 SELECT
  user_pseudo_id,
  event_params.value.int_value AS session_id
FROM
  `xx-realtime-ga4-data.analytics_252663028.events_intraday_20231222`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS event_params
WHERE
  event_params.key = 'ga_session_id'
```

It is returning multiple user_pseudo_id values against the same ga_session_id

How is this possible?

Here is the example of the two user_pseudo_id's:

1. BTEu3pVyjeOHMhfkXEHCTxNzm5wv/KYYCYe30X4kYqQ=.1703165243
2. 1041281587.1703165243

They seem to be linked as the second part of the client_id is in both ids....

What is the scenario that is causing this to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue may be due to incorrect configuration of user_pseudo_id or using a user_property dimension that relies on cookies for user_pseudo_id (cid). consider that the first format is not the correct format for user_pseudo_id.
and your question about scenarios? , yes it is possible. This is because the session_id is the timestamp of the starting session, and it's possible for two users to start their session at the same timestamp, To accurately count the number of sessions, you need to count the distinct number of concatenated values of user_pseudo_id and ga_session_id.